# Why am I getting the " 'NoneType' object is not callable " error when I apply model.fit in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm getting the following error why I apply model.fit. I've described my model and other variables after this error.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 results = model.fit({'title_input': sequences_matrix_train_t, 'body_input': sequences_matrix_train_b},
> 2           {'main_output': y_train, 'aux_output': y_train},
> 3           validation_data=[{'title_input': sequences_matrix_test_t, 'body_input': sequences_matrix_test_b},
> 4           {'main_output': y_test, 'aux_output': y_test}],
> 5           epochs=5, batch_size=800)
>
> ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
> 107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> --> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 109
> 110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.
>
> ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers,
> use_multiprocessing)    1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
> 1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
> -> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)    1099               if data_handler.should_sync:    1100
> context.async_wait()
>
> ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
> 778       else:
> 779         compiler = "nonXla"
> --> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> 781
> 782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
>
> ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py
> in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
> 805       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
> 806       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
> --> 807       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
> 808     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
> 809       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Getting the above error when I fit my model. The model is described below:-

```
def RNN():

# RNN part for the title column
title_input = Input(name='title_input',shape=[max_len_of_title_tokens])
title_Embed = Embedding(vocab_len_t+1,2000,input_length=max_len_of_title_tokens,mask_zero=True,name='title_Embed')(title_input)
gru_out_t = GRU(300)(title_Embed)

# Using dense method for auxillary output to smoothen the effects of the GRU
auxiliary_output = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(gru_out_t)   

# RNN part for the body column
body_input = Input(name='body_input',shape=[max_len_of_body_tokens]) 
body_Embed = Embedding(vocab_len_b+1,170,input_length=max_len_of_body_tokens,mask_zero=True,name='body_Embed')(body_input)
gru_out_b = GRU(200)(body_Embed)

# combining these two
combined = concatenate([gru_out_t, gru_out_b])

# Feeding combined to our remaining two dense layers
dense1 = Dense(400,activation='relu')(combined)
dropout = Dropout(0.5)(dense1)
batchNormalizer = BatchNormalization()(dropout) 
dense2 = Dense(150,activation='relu')(batchNormalizer)

main_output = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(dense2)

model = Model(inputs=[title_input, body_input],outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])

return model

#python function ends, stack overflow wouldn't let me indent lol.
#below is the code outside the 'RNN' function. 

model = RNN() #this 'model' variable is the one over which I apply the 'fit' method.

#Here's how I'm applying the fit method:-
results = model.fit({'title_input': sequences_matrix_train_t, 'body_input': sequences_matrix_train_b},
      {'main_output': y_train, 'aux_output': y_train},
      validation_data=[{'title_input': sequences_matrix_test_t, 'body_input': sequences_matrix_test_b},
      {'main_output': y_test, 'aux_output': y_test}],
      epochs=5, batch_size=800)
```

Can someone please look over my error and help me figure out why it's being caused.

Here's my jupyter notebook for more info – https://github.com/datares/teamRed/blob/main/post_classification.ipynb

Comment: Are you sure that the way you're providing loss functions during compile is valid? I don't see any reference to using dictionaries for the loss functions in the documentation - can you try it as an array similar to `outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output]` in the Model call?